# Extract Type - Tracking Extract - Journey name

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, data-export, tracking

I've created a series of Tracking Extracts on my account.  Which field should I use to export the Journey Name that is associated with the email data of each extract?

Comment: I don't think you can do this directly. You have to use SQL Query for this. here is the list of the fields and their description https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_extract_types_reference.htm&type=5 I do not see any journey name field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to track the email sent from journey then you can use the [sent tracking output](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_sent.htm&type=5) from tracking extract.

Once you are done with the tracking extract and file transfer activity. You can the get the file from SFMC SFTP and filter with the 'TriggeredSendExternalKey'. You can find your journey triggered send external key by going into `Email Studio > Email > Interactions > Journey builder sends > Select your journey`.

Take the csv or extract the zip file from SFTP and filter it with your journey builder triggered send external key.

Since this tracking extract involves so much of activity i would prefer SQL query if I need the data of less than 180 days.

Here is the [salesforce documentation for last 24 hours of journey builder sends](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_query_journey_builder_sends_in_last_24_hours.htm&type=5). You can extend as per your convenient if its withing 180 days.

If its more than 180 days then you can go with this tracking data extract option.