# Include The journey name in Data extract file

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, ftp, data-extract

I'm working on a data extraction. I implemented it with a file transfer to my FTP, it's for "Sent" journey feedbacks. My customer would like to have the "journey name" in the generated file. I have just the "TriggeredSendExternalKey" for the moment, the customer really wants the journey name instead.

Thank you in advance,
Ilyass

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a query to populate the DE that you are then extracting? If so, you can match the TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID on the [_Sent](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5) data view to the JourneyActivityObjectID on the [_JourneyActivity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_journey_activity.htm&type=5) data view. Then you can match VersionID on the _JourneyActivity to VersionID on the [_Journey](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_journey.htm&type=5) data view, in order to retrieve the JourneyName from the _Journey data view.

Here is an example query that can be tailored to your needs:

```
select
j.JourneyName
from _Sent s
inner join _JourneyActivity ja on ja.JourneyActivityObjectID = s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID 
inner join _Journey j on j.VersionID = ja.VersionID 
where s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = 'YOUR_TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID'
```

Comment: I don't use DEs, because the type of extraction that I use is "Tracking extract". So the extraction is done automaticaly without SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

It is still advised to use SQL for such use-case, as @jake314159 suggested already. [Here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_query_journey_builder_sends_in_last_24_hours.htm&type=5) you can find a step-by-step explanation of his suggestion and a bit more on top.

Additionally, there is a similar [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306462/extract-type-tracking-extract-journey-name) has been asked some time ago and there you find a way how to manually map `TriggeredSendExternalKey` and identify what was the journey used for sending.

There is no special option to add the `Journey Name` field to the Tracking Extract's file. Maybe the only thing to try is to set some field that you would receive in the file that would include Journey's name, e.g. `EmailName` field from [SendJob](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_sendjobs.htm&type=5) would have a naming pattern like - `[Journey_Name]_Email_#1`. but then you would need to make sure that you are not re-using emails across different journeys.

Comment: The Tracking Data Extract was a nice feature until new features such as journey builder were added without updating the data extract output to include journey info. If the Sent extract included a TriggererSendDefinitionObjectId that would be a good start to fixing what is missing. If that field name's spelling could be be corrected to say TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectId that would be amazing.